# How to Calculate Delta Phi Psi between aligned pair of residue between Reference and Target Protein Structure in Pymol

Tags: pymol

I aligned multiple protein structures from the same protein family to a reference structure in pymol and now I want to calculate the Difference in Phi psi values for each 'aligned' residue pair between Reference Structure and each Target Structure, I have extracted the phi psi values using phi_psi command and I have the sequence alignment but I don't know how to extract Delta Phi Psi values for every aligned residue between Reference and Target.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.